# How to catch the opening of dialogue window "Raise volume above safe level?"

Tags: android

Maybe there is some event that occurs when opening a dialogue?

Unsafe volume warning:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is styled like a dialog, that is most likely an activity. You have no good way to know when that specific activity is displayed.